# Replace a words which occurs in between the two words + ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to replace some words in a string, and I know I can use a `gsub` method. But my scenario is suppose I have a following string:

```
"(_query_:"{!edismax qf='judgment_order_text^3.0  parallel_citation_text^3.5 judgment_order_exact^3.0 in_favor_of_exact^3.5 parallel_citation_exact^3.5 judge_names_exact^3.5 headnote_exact^3.3 headline_exact^3.3 court_level_exact^3.5 section_index_exact^3.5 appellant_exact^3.5 respondent_exact^3.5 year_exact^3.5 assessment_years_exact^3.5 AND _query_:"{!edismax qf='in_favor_of_text^1.3 in_favor_of_ngram^0.8 in_favor_of_exact^3.5' mm='1' pf='in_favor_of_text^1.0 in_favor_of_ngram^1.0 in_favor_of_exact^5.0'}revenue")"
```

now I want to replace `exact` word which is occurring in between the `(_query_:` and `AND _query_:` . How to do that by using a ruby ?

I am expecting following output:

```
"(_query_:"{!edismax qf='judgment_order_text^3.0  parallel_citation_text^3.5 AND _query_:"{!edismax qf='in_favor_of_text^1.3 in_favor_of_ngram^0.8 in_favor_of_exact^3.5' mm='1' pf='in_favor_of_text^1.0 in_favor_of_ngram^1.0 in_favor_of_exact^5.0'}revenue")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) or [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub). Here:

```
a = "\"(_query_:\"{!edismax qf='judgment_order_text^3.0  parallel_citation_text^3.5 judgment_order_exact^3.0 in_favor_of_exact^3.5 parallel_citation_exact^3.5 judge_names_exact^3.5 headnote_exact^3.3 headline_exact^3.3 court_level_exact^3.5 section_index_exact^3.5 appellant_exact^3.5 respondent_exact^3.5 year_exact^3.5 assessment_years_exact^3.5 AND _query_:\"{!edismax qf='in_favor_of_text^1.3 in_favor_of_ngram^0.8 in_favor_of_exact^3.5' mm='1' pf='in_favor_of_text^1.0 in_favor_of_ngram^1.0 in_favor_of_exact^5.0'}revenue\")\"\n" 

replacement = "\"{!edismax qf='judgment_order_text^3.0  parallel_citation_text^3.5"

puts a.sub(a[/_query_:(.*) AND _query_/, 1], replacement)
# "(_query_:"{!edismax qf='judgment_order_text^3.0  parallel_citation_text^3.5 AND _query_:"{!edismax qf='in_favor_of_text^1.3 in_favor_of_ngram^0.8 in_favor_of_exact^3.5' mm='1' pf='in_favor_of_text^1.0 in_favor_of_ngram^1.0 in_favor_of_exact^5.0'}revenue")"
```

Comment: I just want to remove `the string which contains the exact with blank("") like str.gsub(/\w+_text\^\d+.*\d*/, '')` which are occuring in between the `(_query_:` and `AND _query_:`